# make an association in Java (1 0..n)

Tags: associations, uml

I have a Problem implementing an Association in Java.

I have three Classes : Attraction, Ticket, tour group.

An Attraction can have no ticket, one or more than one ticket (0..*).
A Ticket is related exactely to a tour group.
A Ticket know her Tour Group, but the Tour Group doesn't know the Ticket.

I made it to implement the Unidirectional relation between the ticket and the tour group by making an attribute in the Ticket class.

```
private Reisegruppe reisegruppe
```

and creating a get method for it :

```
//get reisegruppe
    public Reisegruppe getReisegruppe() {
        return reisegruppe;
    }
```

But I still can't Implement the relation between the Attraction and the Ticket.

Thanks Alot.

Comment: In order to make your question clearer it would help to: (1) show also the UML class diagram (including the expected [navigability](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability)) in addition to your text description of the relationships. (2) don't use different names for the same thing ("tour group", "Tour Group", "Reisegruppe")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't fullly explain your idea of a relation between the `Attraction` and the `Ticket` classes. Is it one-to-many or many-to-many? In the first case, you could implement it in the `Ticket` class with a single-valued reference property like

> private Attraction attraction;

while in the second case you would need a multi-valued reference property like

> private List < Attraction > attractions;

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way. One more property for Ticket:

```
public Attraction getAttraction() {
    return attraction;
}
```

Of course, you should make also setters and fields themselves.

This way any attraction and any group can have any number of tickets.

Do not forget to check the limitation: Ticket can not have null Attraction.